# How do I configure Tomcat 6 so that JSP files in one subdirectory will not be executed?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Assume that I have a webapp running on a Tomcat 6 server with the following directory structure.

```
/home/
/home/css/
/home/images/
/home/inc/
/home/js/
/home/uploads/
```

I want to disallow execution of JSP files in /home/uploads/ because there should not be any there.  Is there a way to do that in the standard Tomcat 6 config?  By "standard" I mean using no 3rd party add-ons or plug-ins, base Tomcat install only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do, IMHO, would be to put the uploads directory outside of the webapp folder.

If you really want to leave it there, you could simply add a servlet filter to your app that is mapped to `/home/uploads`, and returns an error in case the URL ends with `.jsp`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Writing a custom filter class was easy enough and configuring it in Tomcat was also simple.